# I want to hide a link at a certain width. How?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, width, hide

I am trying to hide a link when the windows width becomes below 600 pixels.
I have tried and I have looked for a way to do this, but so far i haven't found anything that seems to work. i tried with the:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #hideme {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

which didn't work for me.. Feel free to check out the jsFiddle

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nBZxc/)

Comment: why did you include media Query in Question,and jScript in fiddle? you can use media Query for this. Are you going to use javascript 1000 times like say ,windowsize -> this ,then this . Much Better way is using mediaQuery for responsive design

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width : 600px) {}  must work,Check what did you do wrong,instead of going throught jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS media queries should work. Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nBZxc/2/

For jQuery version, you can use `$(document).width()` instead of `document.width`:

```
if($(document).width() > 600)
{
    $("#hideme").hide();
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nBZxc/1/)**

Comment: @PratikJoshi See fiddle

Comment: Doesn't necessarily needs to be css, I will try this method and get back to you!

Comment: the CSS media queries worked when I used the css in the fiddle for some reason, when mine didn't. Well the css works great, and the jquery workes aswell. Thanks for getting back to me so fast!

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(window).width() > 600)
{
    $("#hideme").hide();
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Zest4/

Answer (score 0):

Hello i used media Queries for hiding you content on Window width resize

http://jsfiddle.net/nBZxc/3/

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 600px) {
    #hideme{display: none!important;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have more idea about css, But you can hide element by js.

```
if($("#element_id").width() > 600){
  $(this).hide();
  /* or
  $(this).css('display', 'none');
  */
}
```